# Vector space of matrices over field of rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ denote the set of all $(m\times n)$ matrices with real entries. Let $F$ be the field of rational numbers. Is $V$ a vector space over $F$ with the usual definitions of matrix addition and multiplication?

My attempt:

1. Let $A,B \in V$. Then $(A+B) \in V$
2. Let $c \in \mathbb Q.$ Then $c\cdot A \in V$
3. Let $A,B \in V$. Then $(A+B)=(B+A)$
4. Let $A,B,C \in V$. Then $(A+B)+ C= A+ (B+C)$
5. There exists $0$-matrix $\in V$ such that $A+0=A$
6. For each $A\in V$, there exists $(-A)\in V$ such that $A+(-A)=0$
7. Let $I_{m\times n} \in \mathbb Q$. Then $I_{m\times n} \cdot A=A \in V$

It is at this point that I'm stuck. I need to prove that:

1. If $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, then $(ab)A=a(bA)$
2. If $ c\in \mathbb Q$, then $c\cdot(A+B)=c\cdot A+c\cdot B$
3. If $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, then, $(a+b)\cdot A= a\cdot A+ b\cdot A$

I am guessing that one of these won't be true? How do I check these?

Comment: May I ask what are you doing?

Comment: I'm doing vector spaces, proving or disproving that a given set on a given field is a vector space.

Comment: Then what is $I_{m\times n}\in\mathbb Q$? I assume $m\neq n$?

Comment: I missed the part that it isn't a square matrix. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe matrices in terms of their entries. For example, to prove your outstanding property (1), the $ij$ entry of $(ab)C$ is

$(ab)c_{ij} = a(b c_{ij})$,

which is the $ij$ entry of $a(b C)$. Your (2) and (3) are similar.

Also, I assume your (7) is supposed to be the existence of a multiplicative unit, but this is always just the multiplicative unit of the underlying field $F$, and in general this is not an element of the vector space itself, unless, e.g., you are treating a field as a vector space over itself.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I should take $1\in \mathbb Q$ as the multiplicative unit... Either way, all 10 properties are satisfied and it is a vector space, right?

Comment: Yes, and note that you didn't use anywhere that your underlying field was $\mathbb{Q}$, so you've actually proved the space of $m \times n$ with entries in any fixed field $F$ is a vector space. In fact, (as a vector space) it is isomorphic to $F^{mn}$.